# Loading data as per the below logic

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift

A banking application which runs every day and generates one csv file (which has account details) and we will load the data into the database.

On the next day, one more daily file will get generated. In this file, for some account numbers, the details have been updated/modified/deleted.
While inserting this in to the database, how can we load only the data that has been altered.

flow is csv file->HDFS-> transformation in hive/spark if applicable-> redshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create HDFS location `/banking`

Load first CSV directly into Hadoop into a folder `/banking/dt=20180529`. Skip the database unless you're actually querying it.

Generate a Hive table over it, partitioned by `dt STRING`.

On the next day, load second CSV into `/banking/dt=20180530`.

After the file is uploaded, use Hive to find all rows that existed for current day that also existed yesterday, optionally creating new table from it

```
-- CREATE TABLE changed_accts AS
SELECT acct --, other columns 
FROM table 
WHERE dt = '20180530' 
AND acct IN (SELECT acct FROM table WHERE dt = '20180529')
```

This should filter out brand new accounts for the day. And I'm assuming deleted accounts won't show up at all. You'll need extra data to determine only updates (like an account balance change)

Comment: Thanks mate for your time and indeed a valuble inputs :) Definitely I am gonna work on this . We shall see :)